# Open Downloads Directory With Finder Prompting User for Permission If Necessary

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm building a BitTorrent client where I give the user an option, through a context menu, to open the containing directory of a torrent.

To do so, I tried using `open(_)` method of an `NSWorkspace` instance like so:

```swift
NSWorkspace.shared.open(directory)
```

where `directory` is an `URL` instance pointing to a directory, like so:

```swift
let directory = URL(fileURLWithPath: item.parentPath, isDirectory: true)
```

Here, `item.parentPath` is a String holding an absolute path.

Now, let me clear up that the code runs fine. It successfully opens up the directories I want inside Finder (since it's the default application for opening directories).

However, if the directory happens to be the *Downloads* directory of the user, it displays this prompt:

[image: Operation rejected due to lack of permissions.]

Again, this is alright since my application does not have permission to open the *Downloads* directory. However, I want to attempt to open the directory, asking for permission, just like any other application on macOS, like so:

[image: Prompting for permission.]

I looked up in the docs and found this method of `NSWorkspace`: `open(_:withApplicationAt:configuration:completionHandler:)`. I thought it was great since I could set the `promptsUserIfNeeded` property of an `NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration` instance to *true*, which I believe should make my application politely ask for permission to open the directory if needed.

Here's my resulting code:

```swift
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: item.parentPath, isDirectory: true)

let configuration: NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
configuration.promptsUserIfNeeded = true

let finder = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.finder")

// Open file with default application
NSWorkspace.shared.open([url], withApplicationAt: finder!, configuration: configuration)
```

Sadly, it's making no difference. I'm still getting the same dialog as shown in the first image.

I want to know two things:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I open a directory, prompting for permissions if necessary?

Comment: Why can't I ask for necessary permissions right when I need it?

Comment: "if the app doesn't have any possible permissions then there is nothing to ask for, right?"

Sorry but it makes little sense since most of my macOS apps ask for permission right when they need it, not during installation.

Comment: I actually checked the Signing & Capabilities. It says that my app has read/write permissions of the Downloads directory. Despite that the problem persists.

Comment: I wonder if your issue is actually around `fileURLWithPath`. Try just creating a file URL manually; e.g. (In ObjC, sorry) `[NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/username/Downloads"];`. That works for me (in a sandboxed app, I needed to ensure "read" permissions on the Downloads directory is enabled in the sandbox)

Comment: I tried doing that too. Makes no difference. I have both read/write permissions on the Downloads directory as per my entitlements file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you want this all to play nicely within the sandbox. You have two choices:

1. Use [`activateFileViewerSelecting(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1524549-activatefileviewerselecting) or [`selectFile(_:inFileViewerRootedAtPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1524399-selectfile). Either of these will prompt for permission, & once gained, you can return to using [`open(_:withApplicationAt:configuration:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3172702-open), if you so wish.
2. Use [Security-Scoped Bookmarks and Persistent Resource Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16).

Comment: Thank you so much. However, isn't it a bit hacky? If I open something once for sake of obtaining permission and open once more for the original intent, won't I end up with 2 Finder windows? This isn't exactly what I'd like to do.